# Run downloaded files in Google Chrome/Firefox instead of saving them like in IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, download, temporary-internet-files

In Internet Explorer, there is a very good option while trying to download something: *Run* (it comes before *Save*).

With this option the file (i.e an installer file) will be downloaded to `Temporary Internet Files` and instantly runs after it's finished downloading. Then, the installation process begins.

After the installation, the installer source file will be deleted (I think so), since in many cases we don't need it anymore.

In other browsers such as Google Chrome or Firefox, this option doesn't exist. Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: If you still need this in Chrome you can express your wish about the missing feature on this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68200 and star it to get updates

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful for Firefox. And I've heard that for Chrome it's still impossible: [Directly Run Downloads Without Saving Them In Firefox](http://techie-buzz.com/featured/directly-run-downloads-without-saving-them-in-firefox.html)

Unfortunately, it really doesn't work.

I've tried this one and it added a *Run* button to my Firefox 7:

> [**OpenDownload²**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-10902/)
>
> OpenDownload² inserts a "Run" button into the "Open File" dialog when downloading files. Clicking the button saves the particular file in your temporary directory and opens it with the assigned application or (for .exe files) runs the application from there.

Comment: Thanks. Seems the Add-on mentioned in the link, became unavailable for some reason: "This add-on has been disabled by an administrator."  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rundownload/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an add-on to get this in FF or Chrome.  Something like [**OpenDownload**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload/) for FF.  I don't know of one for Chrome, although there is an [**open feature request**](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=668afecd95c35705&hl=en) to add it.

Comment: Thanks. Although there is no official way to add open option to a download situation on chrome, I've found this concept as a personal work:   http://goo.gl/2Vfkt